# Expectation of minimum of two random numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let's assume we picked chose two numbers in the range $[1,n]$ where $n\in \mathbb N$ independently, such that each one of them is distributed randomly.

How can I find the expectation of the minimum of these two numbers?

I know that we have $2n-1$ possibilities of getting $1$ as minimum, $2(n-1)-1$ possibilities of getting $2$ as minimum, and so on!

But how do I formalize this and calculate the expectation?

Comment: Do you mean you have a discrete uniform distribution with support $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$? You first consider the CDF / Survival function and then link it with the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1 \le k \le n$, let $p_k$ be the probability that the minimum of the two numbers is $k$, and let $e$ be the expected minimum value.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;p_k &= 
2
\left(
{\small{\frac{1}{n}}}
\right)
\left(
{\small{\frac{n-k+1}{n}}}
\right)
-
{\small{\frac{1}{n^2}}}
\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2n-2k+1}{n^2}\\[8pt]
\text{Hence}\;\;e &=\sum_{k=1}^n kp_k\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k\left(\frac{2n-2k+1}{n^2}\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  k(2n-2k+1)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (2n+1)k-2k^2)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (2n+1)k\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 2k^2)\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(
\left((2n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)
-
\left(2\sum_{k=1}^n k^2)\right)
\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n^2}
\left(
(2n+1)
\left({\small{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}\right)
-2
\left({\small{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}}\right)
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple but extremely useful fact:

> **Fact** For a non-negative integer-valued random variable $Z$, 
>   $$
> \mathrm{E}[Z] = \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathrm{P}(Z\ge k).
> $$

That said, for iid $X,Y$
$$
\mathrm{E}[\min(X,Y)] = \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathrm{P}(\min(X,Y)\ge k) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathrm{P}(X\ge k,Y\ge k) \\
= \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathrm{P}(X\ge k)\mathrm{P}(Y\ge k) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathrm{P}(X\ge k)^2.
$$
In particular, if the distribution is uniform on $\{1,\dots,n\}$, then 
$$
\mathrm{E}[\min(X,Y)] = \sum_{k= 1}^n \mathrm{P}(X\ge k)^2 = \sum_{k= 1}^n \frac{(n-k+1)^2}{n^2} = \frac1{n^2}\sum_{j= 1}^n j^2 \\ = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}.
$$

*Exercise*. Compute $\mathrm{E}[\min(X_1,X_2,X_2)]$, where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are iid uniform on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Please replace $\max$ by $\min$ four times.

Comment: Nice solution! (once the typos are fixed).

Comment: @Did, thanks, fixed.

Comment: +1 from me, in particular because the technique generalizes easily.