# Expected Value of two numbers, drop lowest

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Assume I take two real numbers in the range $[a,b]$ where $a, b\in \mathbb R$ and $a < b$, such that both of them are distributed randomly. I then drop the lowest of these two. What is the expected value?

All of the approaches I've seen to the version of this problem where $a, b\in \mathbb N$ have been brute-forced. A piece of software that calculates a similar scenario assumes the answer is $\frac{a}{3}+\frac{2*b}{3}$, but after trying to simulate it on my own a bunch I'm convinced that that answer is *slightly* off.

Comment: Apologies if this question is too basic or my terminology is off -- I've forgotten most of my math classes from undergrad. Unsure if this is proper etiquette here, but the best related question I found is: [Expectation of minimum of two random numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407805/expectation-of-minimum-of-two-random-numbers?newreg=c4f6240bfcdf41358366074fd8143102), which is for natural numbers and fixes a at 1.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the expected value of the maximum of two independent uniformly distributed random variables (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\max\{X,Y\}]$ with $X,Y \sim U(a,b)$). 
If so, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197304/994301) should answer your question.

Comment: If you can solve the problem for uniformly sampled interval $[0,1]$, the expected *maximum* of two numbers can be found for any finite interval.  It isn't clear what being "brute-forced" means to you, but a straightforward derivation would involve integrating over the unit square.

Comment: @GraffL ah yup that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks! I guess there must be something wrong with my code -- my numerical approach for $a=1, b=20$ came out to something close but kept on being above $13.\overline{3}$, closer to $13.6$.
@ hardmath Oh, I see. However, I wasn't sure how to solve it over uniformly sampled interval $[0, 1]$ either.